# what is this syntax mean [(f, s) for f, s in zip(first, second) if not f == s] in python

Tags: python

```
first = "Patient has cancer"
second = "bhagwat has cancer"

def _transpositions(first, second):
    d = [(f, s) for f, s in zip(first, second) if not f == s]
    print(d)
_transpositions(first,second)
```

its output is :

> [('a', 'h'), ('t', 'a'), ('n', 'a'), (' ', 't'), ('h', ' '), ('a', 'n')]

please explain.

Comment: what part in particular do you not understand?

Comment: also note that your claimed output is not the same as the actual output.

Comment: Look up '`zip()`' and 'list comprehension'

Comment: @Duncan I am using pyjarowinkler package it's distance.py file has this code. i am trying to convert that code into C# but i am not able to understand this syntax please explain the full syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code you refer to is a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk). It is equal to the code:

```
d = []
for f, s in zip(first, second):
    if not f == s:
        d.append((f, s))
```

It returns an array of tuples `(f, s)` for each `f, s` in `zip(first, second)` where `f` does not equal `s`.